# flag provided but not defined: -targetgaslimit

Tags: gas-limit, command-line

I've typed `targetgaslimit` option, however it has returned the following error.

```
enter preformatted text here flag provided but not defined: -targetgaslimit
```

The following is the command.

```
$ geth --networkid "11" --nodiscover --datadir "hoge" --genesis "/hoge/myGenesis.json" --port "1234" --mine --targetgaslimit "4712388" --unlock myCoinbase --rpc --rpcaddr "localhost" --rpcport "8545" --rpccorsdomain "*" console
```

Is the `targetgaslimit` option eliminated?

Comment: why do you have it twice in your cmd line?\

Comment: Sorry, it's a mistake.I've edited it.

Comment: and does it work now, because mine works...

Comment: Is it work in your condition? I'll try it.

Comment: @RolandKofler It didn't work in my condition.

Comment: what geth version?

Comment: @RolandKofler  Could you show me your command?

Comment: Version: 1.3.6 Should I update to 1.4.0?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42288/discussion-between-roland-kofler-and-toshikaseda).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `--targetgaslimit` flag was added in [this](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/commit/f0cbebb19f3137ee3ba0e66dadd1b5b9dbf98b1c) commit, which was included in version 1.4.0. If you're running an earlier version you'll need to update.

---

### How to determine which release it's in:

On the page showing the committed code there's a blue box at the top showing the commit comment. At the bottom of that box is a line that says `Master`, which is the name of the branch, and a tag icon, which shows `v1.4.9` (which is the current version). Clicking on the `...` icon next to the tag shows a list of release versions in which this commit is incorporated. The first (oldest) one is `v1.4.0`.

Comment: I hadn't read the extended chat discussion that Roland had with the OP. The recommendation there was also to update to at least 1.4.0 - happy to delete my answer and let Roland have credit :)

Comment: Since at least 1.10.26-stable ```--targetgaslimit``` is not available.